# Why does the this arithmetic equal 10 and not 0 with a mod in Java

Tags: java, modulus

I'm working on an old exam for a test and this code is printing the value of 10 for longVariable. Now, by hand, to me, the math would go 9 + 1 % 10 = remainder of 0, not 10... How am I wrong on this?

Thank you for helping!

```
 public class ExamSectionA
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int intVariable1 = 9;
    int intVariable2 = 10;
    double doubleVariable = 11.2;
    char charVariable = 'A';
    long longVariable;
    longVariable = intVariable1 + 1 % intVariable2;
    intVariable2 = (int) (doubleVariable / 10f);
    String[] theirSalary = {"10","20","30","40"};
    System.out.println(intVariable2);
    System.out.println(longVariable); 
}
}
```

EDIT: PEMDAS. Think I got it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Watch your order of operations:

```
intVariable1 + 1 % intVariable2;
```

is:

```
intVariable1 + (1 % intVariable2);
```

So `9 + 1 % 10` is being parsed as `9 + (1 % 10)`. Which gives `9 + 1 = 10`.

`%` has higher precedence than `+`.

Answer (score 3):

% operator has higher priority than +. For more information go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
Corrected code: (intVariable1 + 1) % intVariable2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean instead `(9+1) % 10` ?